# Is it OK to add class to HTML elements just to name them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it good practice to add classes to HTML elements just to name them / make it easier to read?

There's a project I'm looking and in the code many HTML elements have classes that aren't used in CSS or JS, they seem to be there just to name elements.

Example:

```html
<div class="card-body">...</div>
```

Where `card-body` serves no purpose.

What I usually do is to put a comment if I see it can help read the code:

```html
<!-- Card body -->
<div>...</div>
```

Is it OK to have unused classes in HTML code?

Comment: Well it depends on what you like better, it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: It's good to add a class. You can identify the element easily and you may need to do some task later with the class.

Comment: It is obvious that we need to minify our CSS files to make them smaller and our website faster. When you use minify tools for CSS, they remove your comments but not your classes. So it's better to use comments to make your code more readable and then, minify your files to make them smaller. You can use a bunch of tools to find unused classes.

Comment: I'd say the class attribute approach gives you more flexibility for future maintenance or modification of the code: let's say one day your customer decides to re-brand and suddenly the new color scheme dictate a background color for the cards body or the marketing team decides that a little animation is just what you need to engage the visitors... well, in a case like that you already have a viable selector in place.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not intend to tap in to the class and manipulate the element to which the class belongs it will be better to just add a comment instead.
You’re basically adding something in your HTML code that you’re not in need of, as a standard coding practise it’s better to keep your code as concise as possible.
So if you need to add any information regarding a particular HTML element it’s better to comment it.

Comment: It is really a matter of balancing code optimization vs. code maintainability and scalability. Anyway, nowadays it is not uncommon to see websites importing entire front-end frameworks and libraries only to use a tiny fraction of what they contains; what difference would a few unused class attributes make?